# How to cause rotation on a zipline?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, string

I just had a question concerning zip lines for a personal project I’m working on. How could you increase rotation quickly when designing a zipline so that the user begins to spin quickly. I thought about adding weight to one side and making it lopsided, or attaching an object that resembles a yoyo to the zipline and then attaching a chord to a wall that connects to it to force a spin. So my question is what is the physics behind this and are there any more efficient ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could start the rotation before descending onto the zipline. Imagine a rotating plate on which a person stands, while being connected to the zipline. Then the platform suddenly lowers itself or he lifts his legs, so he can't reach the platform and is only connected to the zipline. And there you go, he starts descending the zipline and you have the desired rapid rotation.

You could of course also use other methods for achieving rotation.